# Create multiple JPA persistent entities from one JSON using Jersey?

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jersey

perhaps someone could point me in the right direction, i'v lurking around for a solution for too long..

I am using jersey to get a json sent to a REST service from POST data, and create an persistent entity to be inserted into my DB. With something like this:

```
    @POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response createRecord(Element element) throws Exception{

    violations = validator.validate(element);

    if (violations.size() > 0) {

        jsonResponse.setSuccess(false);
        jsonResponse.setMessage("TODO error message");
        jsonResponse.setValidationError(this.getValidationErrorList());    

    } 
    else {
        try {  
            em.persist(element);  
            em.flush();
            } 
        catch (PersistenceException e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            jsonResponse.setSuccess(false);
            jsonResponse.setMessage("TODO error");
            }  

    }

            jsonResponse.setSuccess(true);
            jsonResponse.setMessage("Success!");

    return Response.ok().entity(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonResponse)).build();

}
```

However i'd like to construct multiple entities from one json like this:

```
[
{
    "usrcre": 0,
    "usrmod": 0,
    "datmod": null,
    "vaecleint": 40,
    "vaeelecle": "1fdsfds",
    "vaevalcle": "fdsf",
    "vaedsc": "dsfdsf"
},
{
    "usrcre": 0,
    "usrmod": 0,
    "datmod": null,
    "vaecleint": 41,
    "vaeelecle": "1TEST",
    "vaevalcle": "0003",
    "vaedsc": "fdgfdgfdg"
},
{
    "usrcre": 0,
    "usrmod": 0,
    "datmod": null,
    "vaecleint": 42,
    "vaeelecle": "1TEST",
    "vaevalcle": "0004",
    "vaedsc": "Valeur 0004gfdgfdg"
},
{
    "usrcre": 0,
    "usrmod": 0,
    "datmod": null,
    "vaecleint": 43,
    "vaeelecle": "1TEST",
    "vaevalcle": "0005",
    "vaedsc": "Valeur 0005fdgfdgd"
}
```

]

I'v tried using something like:

```
public Response createRecord(List<Element> elements) throws Exception
```

and then trying to iterate in this list and persist every element, but I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

as soon as my method signature includes a list or an array. Am I missing something?

Update:

Here's the stack trace when I tried to access a List (I'm using a "for each" to try and persist every element in the said list, but it seem to always have one empty element no matter how I send my JSON)

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service() for 

servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

edit: Or, if someone has a good workaround idea that doesnt involve parsing the JSON received to create a collection "Element" I would be all hear!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Edited with full stack trace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright problem solved! So here's the "solution":

The function "createRecord" is in a REST service which gets his data from post (@POST). I have a glassfish server setup and do all my tests locally. Turns out that since i didn't **restart** the glassfish server, it was still taking my old annotations from old sources in consideration (I had a @XmlRootElement in my Element class some time ago)

So jersey was mismatching my JSON for Xml data. Hence the IllegalArgumentException. I restarted the server, and my "for each" parsing a List of elements works perfectly!

The old: "Did you try to reboot?" actually worked once again.